# PowerBI - Maximum of a Grouped RollingSum

Tags: powerbi, dax

Im trying to calculate the Maximum value of a rolling sum using PowerBI and DAX.  I have got the rolling sum in the lead time by SKU calculated by adding a DAX measure, which works as needed (DAX expression below).  However, i am now unable to take the results of this, and then calculate the MAX rolling sum per SKU as PowerBI doesnt want me to reference the measure Rolling Sum.

```
Rolling Sum = 
VAR CurrentDate = MAX(dgSalesHistoryTSLRollingSum[Delivery Date])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
SUM('dgSalesHistoryTSLRollingSum'[QtySupplied]),
DATESBETWEEN('dgSalesHistoryTSLRollingSum'[Delivery Date], CurrentDate - Max('dgSalesHistoryTSLRollingSum'[LeadTime(d)]), CurrentDate)
)
```

| SKU | Delivery Date | Lead Time | QtySupplied | Rolling Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 28/03/2023 | 3 | 68 | 68 |
| A | 29/03/2023 | 3 | 32 | 100 |
| A | 30/03/2023 | 3 | 32 | 132 |
| A | 31/03/2023 | 3 | 37 | **169** |
| A | 03/04/2023 | 3 | 12 | 49 |
| A | 04/04/2023 | 3 | 65 | 77 |
| A | 05/04/2023 | 3 | 39 | 116 |
| B | 28/03/2023 | 3 | 539 | 539 |
| B | 29/03/2023 | 3 | 3234 | 3773 |
| B | 30/03/2023 | 3 | 328 | 4101 |
| B | 31/03/2023 | 3 | 2313 | 6414 |
| B | 01/04/2023 | 3 | 759 | **6634** |
| B | 03/04/2023 | 3 | 424 | 3496 |
| B | 04/04/2023 | 3 | 549 | 1732 |
| B | 05/04/2023 | 3 | 383 | 1356 |

I need to obtain the following:

| SKU | Max Rolling Sum |
| --- | --- |
| A | **169** |
| B | **6634** |

I have tried the following:

```
Max Rolling Sum = CALCULATE(MAX(dgSalesHistoryTSLRollingSum\[Rolling Sum\]))
```

However i get an error that the column "Rolling Sum" in table cannot be found or may not be used in this expression.

Comment: The MAX for A should be 539 no ?

Comment: Sorry 539 was meant to be for B..

Comment: I think you mean that the MAX for A is 539 and MAX for B is 6634

Comment: Please see the table again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Max Rolling Sum by SKU should be like below :

```
Max Rolling Sum by SKU = 
MAXX(
    VALUES(dgSalesHistoryTSLRollingSum[SKU]), 
    CALCULATE(MAX(dgSalesHistoryTSLRollingSum[Rolling Sum]))
)
```

[image]

---

**Update :**

I created a calculated table with the measure you already created and in this case it will be considered as a column :

```
Rolling Sum Summarized = 
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    'dgSalesHistoryTSLRollingSum'[Inventory Code], 
    'dgSalesHistoryTSLRollingSum'[Delivery Date],
    "Rolling Sum", [Rolling Sum]
)
```

Then another calculated table where I select only the maximum value for Rolling Sum :

```
    MaxRollingSumTable = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'Rolling Sum Summarized',
    'Rolling Sum Summarized'[Inventory Code],
    "Max Rolling Sum", MAX('Rolling Sum Summarized'[Rolling Sum])
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Amira, thanks for the help.  I get the same error though:

Column 'Rolling Sum' in table 'dgSalesHistoryTSLRollingSum' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression.

Bearing in mind my Rolling Sum is a measure already.

Comment: My main problem is how do i reference a measure in a dax expression actually - as most of the functions require a column reference and not a measure.

Comment: Are you creating a measure or a calculated column ? I replicate what you did and it is working

Comment: The Rolling Sum is a measure in the first table.  I cant use the same expression in a calculated column as the results dont come out correct.   In the second table, when i create a calculated column or measure, i still get an error about not being able to reference the Rolling Sum measure from the first table....

Comment: In your case you should create a measure for Max Rolling Sum by SKU and not a calculated column

Comment: Thats the issue - i cant.  I cant reference the measure in table 1 in the measure for table 2.  It wont allow me

Comment: Big thank you Amira Bedhiafi for your help!  Your solution was perfect